# when i increment the counter it increases by 2 not one. i am using react context for this

Tags: reactjs, react-context

here i called a function addItem in which i increases the value of th cart

```
 <CartItem
                key={`cartItem-${item.item_id}`}
                onIncrement={() => addItem(item)}
                onDecrement={() => removeItem(item)}
                onRemove={() => removeItemFromCart(item)}
                data={item}
              />
```

and my context is

```
const addItemHandler = (item, quantity = 1) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload: { ...item, quantity } });
  };
```

and my reducer for add item in reducer.js

```
export const addItemToCart = (state, action) => {
  const existingCartItemIndex = state.items.findIndex(
    (item) => item.item_id === action.payload.item_id
  );
  if (existingCartItemIndex > -1) {
    const newState = [...state.items];
    newState[existingCartItemIndex].quantity += action.payload.quantity;
    return newState;
  }
  return [...state.items, action.payload];
};
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      return { ...state, items: addItemToCart(state, action) };
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown action: ${action.type}`);
  }
};
```

this code increases the counter by 2 instead on 1.

Comment: What `combineReducer` looks like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that your quantity is being incremented twice is because you would be using `React.StrictMode` which invokes your reducer twice.

This is intentional behaviour and it helps detect side-effects. You must note that if your reducer is a pure function, such a effect will not happen.

In your case you have mutated the quantity value in state which is why you a double increment. Even though you use spread syntax to copy the array, it only performs a shallow copy and the inner objects within it still hold the same reference.

To update it properly you must update the reducer in an immutable way. You can use `Array.prototype.slice` for this purpose

```
export const addItemToCart = (state, action) => {
  const existingCartItemIndex = state.items.findIndex(
    (item) => item.item_id === action.payload.item_id
  );
  if (existingCartItemIndex > -1) {
        const newState = [
           ...state.items.slice(0, existingCartItemIndex),
           {...state.items[existingCartItemIndex], quantity: state.items[existingCartItemIndex].quantity + 1},
           ...state.items.slice(existingCartItemIndex + 1)
        ];
        return newState;
    }
  return [...state.items, action.payload];
};
```

Comment: but when i add a item to cart at first time it gives a error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'quantity' of undefined"

Comment: Seems like you removed the other condition where existingCartItem is false. I updated my post with how the entire function will look like

Comment: thanks for your answers. i've misplaced this code. Now this is working fine.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thanks for your reply, you saved my day!